# Android robust sensor acquisition

Tags: android, service, garbage-collection, singleton

I am developping an app that relies heavily on sensor data. Therefore, I need a framework that will keep on sensing under these conditions:

- keep sensing on low memory (survive Garbage Collection)
- keep sensing after the user wipes the app from the stack
- keep sensing after crash

The problem is that Android is notoriously brutal for garbage collection. The current solution that I have is a foreground Service, which is really bad practice. I want to switch to a singleton object, since the service (even in foreground) doesn't have eternal life. So the first question is simple:

Can static members be garbage collected, for instance when using a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Static members can't be garbage collected, but the app could be killed under low memory conditions, which would erase the singleton when restarted.  What you want isn't really something Android can do-  you sound like you want an RTOS.

Comment: When exactly will the singleton be erased? On reboot? Or when the user starts interacting again? what would the effect of such a singleton be?

Comment: Whenever the application is killed and removed from memory.  Which can be anytime the OS wants, but tends to be when its running low on free RAM.  The result will be the static variable is its default value-  null (for objects), 0 (for ints), false (for booleans) until initialized again.  The entire app would be starting over.